# Slow category page load time after programmatically adding products

Tags: import, category

Would there be any reason why a category page would take a considerably longer amount of time to load after adding products to the website via PHP? This is after reindexing and clearing cache, etc.

Example, after importing 43 config products and 800 simple products to an empty category, page load for that category becomes 12-15 seconds. I have other categories with many times that amount of products (that were added manually) that take only 2-3 seconds to load their pages.

Product pages for these newly imported products load just fine. All attributes show up fine.

Switching to default theme, just to make sure it was nothing on the frontend, doesn't make a difference.

No PHP errors show up in server's log at all, unless I tell it to load a lot of products on one page (100+) then I hit memory errors.

Here is a pastebin of the import code, not sure if it will help. It's looping through one CSV with the configurable product info, then a second CSV with pricing info for each simple product http://pastebin.com/WA7fuJQd

Comment: In case anyone else stumbles on this, the magical answer via Serpyre was USE MAGMI, not Magento's API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply because complex products must process more so are naturally multiple times slower. Likely your other categories only have simple products, normally this comes back to inadequate hosting.

Comment: Wish that were the case, every product on the website is actually a configurable with the exact same set of simple associated products.

Hosting isn't the issue either, running it on a $200 nexcess server with 0 traffic at the moment.

Comment: Ok, I'll take a look at Magmi. Maybe I can integrate it into my current script some how since it says it has an API.

I'll just send the links to show this. htpassword is admin / ggdev.
http://dev.graphicsgarageohio.com/artist/mcg-commissions.html?p=1 category has 369 configurable products, each product has about 20 simple products associated with it. Loads in just a couple of seconds. New category with 43 products generated from PHP script http://dev.graphicsgarageohio.com/artist/joe-pepitone.html?p=1

Comment: To explain why a new script was made, every configurable product has the same simple product setup (same options and prices) so client wanted an easier way of importing and generating products so that they could just enter name, description, image, and category, for just the configurable and be done. That first link is for a category that was populated through CSVs in the normal magento import over time.

Comment: Also, yeah reindexing everything doesn't help  :(  tried running it twice after an import even.

Comment: Yeah, that probably will do the trick, I just wish I knew why it's happening so I could update the script to accommodate. I've browsed through dozens of import tutorials to mimic the fields that people are saving with products this way, but nothing has made a difference. Arg. Thanks for trying

Comment: I could almost kiss you. Magmi is fantastic. Practically instant too (1200 products processed in less than a second). Category page load was fine. Why in the (#*&$* was I not able to find out about this with all my Google searching before I built these scripts, it would have saved me HOURS of time! The API integrates with my scripts just fine.